# Using lapply with more than one item that differs between function calls

Tags: r

I have a frequency cross-tabulation dataset, so columns A01-A04 in the example are counts of CAGs e.g. A01 has 6485 counts of 13 CAGs, 35 counts of 14 CAGs. Each column is a sample. The mode of each sample is the CAG value for which the count is the highest (e.g. 13 for A01).

With the help of stack overflow I've written a function with lapply ('prop') that sums the values in each column above and below the mode, and works out the proportion that are greater than the mode.

However, each sample has a control, as defined in 'settings' e.g. the control for A02 is A01. I would now like to adapt 'prop' so that for each sample it uses its control mode, rather than the sample's own mode. For this it will need to look up which sample it should use in 'settings', then look up the control sample's mode in 'sample mode', then use that value in 'prop'. Unfortunately I believe only one item can vary in each iteration of lapply. I'd be very grateful for help in adapting.

```
#Data set
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15, 17), 
               A01 = c(6485,35,132, 12), 
               A02 = c(0,42,56, 4),
               A03 = c(33,5014,2221, 18),
               A04 = c(106,89,436, 11))

#Define controls for each sample
settings <- data.frame(samples = c('A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04'),
                   control = c('A01', 'A01', 'A03', 'A03')) 

#Mode
samplemode <- data.frame(samples = c('A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04'),
                     samplemode = (data[sapply(data[2:ncol(data)], which.max), ]$CAG))


#Proportion of values > mode ##I NEED TO ADAPT THIS FUNCTION TO CALCULATE     'ctrlprop' USING THE CONTROL MODE OF EACH SAMPLE RATHER THAN 'mod'##
prop <- lapply(data[, 2:ncol(data)], function(x) {
  mod <- data$CAG[which.max(x)] #Calculate mode for each column
  B <- sum(x[data$CAG >= mod]) #Sum heights > mode
  A <- sum(x[data$CAG <= mod]) #Sum heights < mode
  B/(A+B)
})

prop <- as.data.frame(prop) #Convert output from list to data frame
prop <- t(prop) #Transpose so samples in rows and result in columnrm
results <- prop


#Expected results
expected <- data.frame(samples = settings$samples,
                   prop = c(0.5068066, 0.3797468, 0.5896748, 0.4146568),
                   ctrlprop = c(0.5068066, 1.0000000, 0.58967480, 0.73324213))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check `mapply`. It allows us to pass multiple vectors as parameters to a function provided the length of vectors are same. Your function could be modified like this:

```
prop <- mapply(FUN = function(x,mod) {
    B <- sum(x[data$CAG >= mod]) #Sum heights > mode
    A <- sum(x[data$CAG <= mod]) #Sum heights < mode
    B/(A+B)
},data[, 2:ncol(data)], setting$control)
```

A simple example how 'mapply' works:

```
d=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
#>d
#  a b
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 6 

mapply(function(x,y){x+y},d$a,d$b)
#[1] 5 7 9
```

Comment: Thanks, this is now working. I've adapted for my data set as below

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could adapt your `lapply` function to take column names and use them for indexing:

```
res <- lapply(names(data)[-1], function(x){

  mod_cntrl <- samplemode[samplemode$samples == as.character(settings[settings$samples == x,2]),2]

  B <- sum(data[,x][data$CAG >= mod_cntrl]) #Sum heights > mode
  A <- sum(data[,x][data$CAG <= mod_cntrl]) #Sum heights < mode

  mod_smpl <- data$CAG[which.max(data[,x])]

  C <- sum(data[,x][data$CAG >= mod_smpl])
  D <- sum(data[,x][data$CAG <= mod_smpl])

  data.frame(sample=x,prop = C/(C+D),ctrlprop = B/(A+B))

})


> do.call(rbind,res)
  sample      prop  ctrlprop
1    A01 0.5068066 0.5068066
2    A02 0.3797468 1.0000000
3    A03 0.5896748 0.5896748
4    A04 0.4146568 0.7332421
```

I guess this will do just fine, but there might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

​
    settings2 <- data.frame(samples = settings$`Sample file name`, control = settings$`Control sample`)
    res <- lapply(names(height[,7:ncol(height)]), function(x){
    mod_cntrl <- mode[mode$sample == as.character(settings2[settings2$samples == x,2]),2]
    B <- sum(height[,x][height$CAG >= mod_cntrl]) #Sum heights > mode
    A <- sum(height[,x][height$CAG <= mod_cntrl]) #Sum heights < mode
    mod_smpl <- height$CAG[which.max(height[,x])]
    C <- sum(height[,x][height$CAG >= mod_smpl])
    D <- sum(height[,x][height$CAG <= mod_smpl])

```
data.frame(sample=x,prop = C/(C+D),ctrlprop = B/(A+B))
})
```

test <- do.call(rbind,res)